# JS смена позиции DIV

Tags: javascript

Делаю компонент типа скроллера картинок. При смещении в цикле for элемента div (меняю marginLeft), не происходит "по кадровое" смещение div =( в конце цикла div тупо появляется в новой точке. Как бы сделать смещение div как бы по кадрам (чтобы было видно смещение на каждый пиксель).

```
var el = document.getElementById("div2");

for(i=0; i<img_w; i++){

ml--;

el.style.marginLeft = ml + "px";

}
/*
img_w - это размер картинки по ширине
ml - это переменная в которой хранится текущее MarginLeft (по умолчанию ml=0)

*/
```

спасибо заранее.

Comment: джаваскрипт работает со скоростью, в тысячи раз превышающую реакцию человеческого глаза на ваше событие отрисовки :) тут через сетТаймаут нужно покадровку сделать, или с помощью ждквери функции анимейт()

Comment: ок, попробую.

Comment: @deivan тут даже не то, DOM не рендерится до окончания функции обычно. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/mV44Q/

Comment: А в чем проблема использовать `jQuery` к примеру метод `animate`

Comment: ))) Это я так к примеру

    $('button').on('click',
        function() {
           $('div').stop().animate({
              marginLeft: 250
           })
        }
    )

Comment: Да как на JQuery это сделать я знаю =)
я именно на чистом JS извращался.
все сделал при помощи setTimeout!

Comment: Тогда лучше уже setInterval использовать )